Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectError: An error occurred while connecting: 2: No such file or directory
sudo landscape-config --computer-title "My Web Server" --account-name standalone  -p 8965752286 --url https://server.local/message-system
--ping-url http://server.local/ping

2024-07-13 10:31:43,827 ERROR    [PoolThread-twisted.internet.reactor-0] Error contacting the server at https://server.local/message-system.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/fetch.py", line 116, in fetch
curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (77, '')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/client/broker/transport.py", line 81, in exchange
curly, data = self._curl(spayload, computer_id, exchange_token,
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/client/broker/transport.py", line 55, in _curl
return (curl, fetch(self._url, post=True, data=payload,
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/fetch.py", line 118, in fetch
raise PyCurlError(e.args[0], e.args[1])
landscape.lib.fetch.PyCurlError: Error 77:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectError: An error occurred while connecting: 2: No such file or directory.
ping server.local
PING server.local (10.213.3.106) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server.local (10.213.3.106): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.707 ms
64 bytes from server.local (10.213.3.106): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.741 ms
64 bytes from server.local (10.213.3.106): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.765 ms

Landscape On Premises releases
The following Landscape On Premises releases are available:
24.04 (installed)
Dear Team, Please help to fix issue with connection. Which logs Do I need to provide?

If someone will find - resolution is next:
before install landscape-client,
dir and config file need to be there
etc/landscape/client.conf
because after first installation your landscape-client try to connect to ubuntu canonical but not to your on-prem server
